# Frontend password reset in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, authentication

Whenever an user requests for password reset it redirects  to domain.com/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword. I don't want Wp-login to be displayed.Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: What do you want to have displayed instead?

Comment: I want everything should be done in front end i.e. on the site itself. I don't want users to know that we are using Wordpress,